# password saver save password in local storage

Tags: javascript, passwords, local-storage

I want to make a password saver that save password and email in array and in local storage
on the user demand it will return the email and password and,
I want to store multiple password and email in array
and it return this on unique id which is stored by user
and store password and email on unique id
please anyone can solve this?
I am fresher and this is my task

can you give me code of JavaScript and with some explanation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following method to you: First of all; saveCredentials: This function accepts an email and password and performs the following steps: generate a unique ID based on the current time, retrieve any existing credentials from local storage, add the new credentials to the stored array using the unique ID, and update the local storage with the modified array.

retrieveCredentials: This function takes a unique ID as input and performs the following steps: retrieve the stored credentials from local storage, find the email and password associated with the provided unique ID in the stored array, and return them as an object.

You can use the saveCredentials function to store new credentials and utilize the retrieveCredentials function to fetch the stored email and password using the unique ID. I hope this answer is useful for you.